# Naive Bayes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, artificial-intelligence, naivebayes

We are trying to do naive bayes classification in Ruby.

Currently we are using http://ai4r.rubyforge.org/

We couldn't get it working for float values and have about 20% points lower accuracy with string values. With float/integers we get a [] no implicit conversion from nil to integer. We convert floats with to_s.

Is there a way to get float values working? If not what are alternative gems to ai4r for ruby or alternative algorithms to naive bayes?

Answer (score 2):

The *"...implicit conversion..."* error is coming from within the Ruby interpreter in a context where an `Integer` is required but a `nil` is found.

It's a bit hard to get this error but one way to see it is:

```
Array.new(nil)
```

...so that's probably what is happening in your case.

And in fact, `gems/ai4r-1.9/lib/ai4r/classifiers/naive_bayes.rb` does actually use the rather rare construct of `Array.new(...)`.

The value passed to Array.new() depends on what [`Ai4r::Data::DataSet`](http://ai4r.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Ai4r/Data/DataSet.html) returns from [`#build_domains.`](http://ai4r.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Ai4r/Data/DataSet.html#M000088)

I know this doesn't solve your problem but perhaps it will help you proceed further with your analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is an older one, but I wanted to point out a more robust Ruby gem for Naive Bayes classification:

https://github.com/oasic/nbayes